# Check if cell is only a-z excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to be sure that all my cell contain only characters (A-Z/a-z). I want to be sure there isn't any symbol, number or anything else. Any tips?

For example I have this "Š".

Comment: Yep. But I was "thinking" it wrong as I am a newbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open the VBA editor (Alt+F11) and create a new module.
- Add a reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" (Tools -> References).
- In your new module, create a new function like this:

  ```
  Function IsAToZOnly(inputStr As String) As Boolean
      Dim pattern As String: pattern = "^[A-Za-z]*$"
      Dim regEx As New RegExp

      regEx.pattern = pattern
      IsAToZOnly = regEx.Test(inputStr)
  End Function
  ```
- Use the new function in your worksheet:

  ```
  =IsAToZOnly(A1)
  ```

Answer (score 3):

As a VBA function, the following should work:

```
Option Compare Binary
Function LettersOnly(S As String) As Boolean
    LettersOnly = Not S Like "*[!A-Za-z]*" And S <> ""
End Function
```

In using the function, S can be either an actual string, or a reference to the cell of concern.

**EDIT**: Also, you want to be certain you have not set `Option Compare Text` in your code.  The default is `Option Compare Binary` which is what you want for this type of comparison.  I have added that to the code for completeness.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that you can match a pattern in VBA without using the RegEx library.

Comment: @Physikbuddha  Very simple patterns only, but sufficient for this requirement.